# windowWillReturnFieldEditor never called for NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nswindow, nstextview

Per protocol ref, windowWillReturnFieldEditor should be called for any text-displaying object when it needs a field editor. Indeed, my window delegate receives a call to this method for textfields, buttons, comboboxes, etc. — but never for textviews.

Is this normal? Does NSTextView carry its own field editor and never request one? Or what am I missing?

```
- (id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)anObject {
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]])
        printf("\nwinWillRtnFldEdtor called for some textview."); // never happens
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drats. Looking at memory addresses of the field editors, it is apparent that every textview does indeed have its own distinct field editor (unlike the textfields, which share a common field editor), and so textviews never request a field editor and never call this method.

Which is unfortunate, since I need special routines to set up multiple distinct textviews just before they become active. (It was easier to do this with textfields.) The best workaround I can think of is to add a tag-like property to the textviews.

Comment: It's more correct to say that every field editor has its own `NSTextView`. A field editor is an `NSTextView` that is reused for all the text fields in a window. Standalone `NSTextView` objects don't need a field editor because they are one.

Comment: @Rob Keniger: Noted. Thanks for the clarification. (Text architecture is kind of confusing.)